# Parsing an object-sequence with Play-JSON library

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

As a disclaimer: I'm very new to Scala and functional programming in general.

I have the following classes:

```
case class A(
  field1: String,
  field2: DateTime
)

case class B(
  listOfStuff: Seq[A]
)

object A{
  def create(field1: String, field2: DateTime): A = A(field1, field2)
}

object B{
  def create(listOfStuff: Seq[A]): B = B(listOfStuff)
}
```

(The `create()` functions exist because I sometimes had issues in my code when using `apply()`. Let's ignore this, I doubt it's relevant.)

I get these objects in JSON format and I try to parse them using the Play-JSON library. An important aspect is that the list (`Seq`) can be missing from the JSON text, it's an optional field.

With that in mind, this is how I wrote that particular line:

```
private implicit val messageReader = (
    //...
    (__ \ "stuff").readNullable[Seq[A]].map(_.getOrElse(Seq()))
    //...
)(B.create _)
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

> Error:(!line!, !column!) No Json deserializer found for type Seq[A].
>   Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

From what I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361994), apparently you need to have an `implicit` instance of `Reads[T]` for every type `T` that is not part of the language (or something like that, did I mention I'm new to this?)

So I also added a secondary `Reads[T]` in the same scope, my code now looked like this:

```
private implicit val messageReader = (
    (__ \ "stuff").readNullable[Seq[A]].map(_.getOrElse(Seq()))
)(B.create _)

private implicit val anotherReader = (
    (__ \ "field1").read[String] and
    (__ \ "field2").read[String].map(org.joda.time.DateTime.parse)
)(A.create _)
```

However I still get that same error on the same line.

I feel like there's some very easy and obvious problem here, but I can't figure out what it is.

How do I fix this?

Comment: To be able to use parsers of `Seq[T]`, parsers for `T` must be available

Comment: @cchantep Which is why I added the `private implicit val anotherReader`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: It must be available *before* (not as a later val)

Comment: @cchantep Your suggestion worked. I simply reversed their order and everything was fine. Post it as an answer and I will accept it ;) .

Answer (score 0):

if `B.create` accepts a single argument then its reads can look like this:

```
private implicit val messageReader : Reads[B] =
  (__ \ "stuff").readNullable[Seq[A]].map(_.getOrElse(Seq())).map(B.create)
```

Comment: Actually they're about 20 fields there, but of course I deleted them for the purpose of this question.